# Drag and Drop with ArcGIS Engine MapControl within WindowsFormsHost in WPF

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, wpf

I have an application that requires dragging and dropping onto ArcGIS Engine's MapControl in a Windowsformhost. I have set the Allowdrop property on both the host and the control itself and it still does not allow me to drop on the control.

Is there a way to enable dropping on the MapControl?

Comment: Do you already have drag and drop working for a simple winforms based control (i.e. not the mapcontrol)?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304869/how-do-you-implement-drag-and-drop-from-a-small-wpf-element-host-in-a-winforms-ap

Comment: We have Drag and Drop working pretty well in WPF controls like Listboxs and such. We fires a drag event already, it's just that I can't figure out how to let MapControl allow the drop and therefore extracting the data from the drag event. The allowdrop property seems to do nothing. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do the following:

1) `Set AxMapControl.OleDropEnabled = true;`

2) `_AxMapControl.OnOleDrop += new IMapControlEvents2_Ax_OnOleDropEventHandler(AxMapControl_OnOleDrop);`

3)

```
private void mapControl_OnOleDrop(object sender, IMapControlEvents2_OnOleDropEvent e) 
{}
```